# Thymeleaf get url attribute

Tags: java, html, spring, url, thymeleaf

I'd like to extract url attributes in thymeleaf template. I'm trying it like this:

Send this query
`http://somedomain/myPage?text=blah`

**myPage.html**

```
<div th:text="${param.text}"></div>
```

Bu instead of **blah** I get `[Ljava.lang.String;@797291bb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${param.text}` resolves to an array.  To get the actual value, you have to use `${param.text[0]}`